# Are Red and Terrence brothers?

Tags: angry-birds

So in the *Angry Birds* movie it is made clear that Red has no family and does not know who his family is. Also they are really the only red birds in town -

[image]

[image]

[image]

Not only are they the only red birds but they look alike! Note the colouring, head feathers and eyebrows, they even have the same eye colour!

[image]

[image]

[image]

They are both very angry too, so is there anything to hint at a possible family connection between the two?

Comment: Are they being introduced to each other, I can't tell; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vd1IOkKr0kk

Comment: @Valorum Yes they are.. When Red gets sent to anger management. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It would appear not.** The official [Angry Birds website](https://www.angrybirds.com/characters/) is rather taciturn (like Terence, in fact) about his upbringing or origins, but there's no mention of him being related to Red.

> Terence is, in fact, quite large. **Little else is known about the big
>   guy** due to the fact that he speaks only in low-pitched growls.

---

There's mention on the (non-official) [Angry Birds wiki](http://angrybirds.wikia.com/wiki/Terence) that he's Red's brother but this seems to stem from a toy-care guide which refers to the large birds as ***"Big Brother Birds***", rather than a specific mention of his being Red's brother.

> Terence, the Big Brother Bird is a character in the Angry Birds series
>   of games created by Rovio Entertainment ... **He is Red's big brother.**

[image]

Comment: But they are so alike!!! Why did they make them so alike?! Just to confuse and frustrate us people who actually sat through their movie? The torture!

Comment: @Rincewind - I get the impression that he's one of a *species* of bird

Comment: It may be so... @valorum

Comment: @Rincewind - I look forward to being proven wrong.